# Migrating from Ant to Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, ant, ormlite

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
     compileSdkVersion 22
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "SOMEID"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I am fairly new to android, so please be aware. The application that I have been working on was under Ant build, and now have to change to Gradle to work with other new dependencies. And now, I am getting the following errors after migration through **Android Studio->Import->Projects**:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK overview-frame.html
>       File1: /Users/taeyounglee/StudioProjects/adr-android/app/libs/ormlite-android-4.45-javadoc.jar
>       File2: /Users/taeyounglee/StudioProjects/adr-android/app/libs/ormlite-core-4.45-javadoc.jar

Below are the ones that are in **libs** folder, I even tried hard-coding the dependencies on the build.gradle as well, but didn't work out:

```
HockeySDK-3.5.0.jar
http-request-4.2.jar
jsr305-2.0.1.jar
libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar
ormlite-android-4.45.jar
ormlite-android-4.45-javadoc.jar
ormlite-android-4.45-sources.jar
ormlite-core-4.45.jar
ormlite-core-4.45-javadoc.jar
ormlite-core-4.45-sources.jar
otto-1.3.4.jar
picasso-2.1.1.jar
```

Any suggestions on this? The app uses ormlite, and requires both .jar files, as when I tried removing either one of those, it just throws compile errors. I tried looking up online about APK overview-frame.html, but can't seem to find reasonable answer. Help much appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can avoid it, stop using the jars. Gradle makes pulling dependencies down from Maven or JCenter super easy.  When adding libraries like this to your projects, start thinking in terms of adding the dependency via accessing JCenter or Maven instead of manually downloading and placing the jar in your project.

```
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.45'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.45'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.7.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.github.kevinsawicki:http-request:6.0'
```

Here's their associating website references:

- [OrmLite](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.j256.ormlite)
- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
- [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)
- [Hockey](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Android)
- [Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project)
- [HTTP Request](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request)

Comment: Note, you don't have to use the latest version.  If you need the specific versions that your jars were, those versions are there too

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a magic. I only added the ormlite dependencies separate from libs, and kept the others. But one question is, so once you compile like this, these dependencies should stay and doesn't get downloaded unless I make changes on those versions, right? I'll definitely upvote you once I have the access to this, thanks!

Comment: It'll re-download the dependencies if you change the version number of it, or if you clean your project.  You should accept this answer, which means clicking the check mark beneath the up/down vote buttons.